# Get selected item from combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

How can I get selected value from combobox in c#?

I tried somthing like this:

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged_1" >
                <ComboBoxItem Name="Brno" IsSelected="True" Content="Brno"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="Item2" Content="Item2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="Item3" Content="Item3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());

    }
```

Message box shows me this *System.Windows.Controls.ComboboxItem: Item2*

I need only to show *Item2*

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `ComboBoxItem` from the `SelectedItem` and cast the `Content` (in your case) to a `string`:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender,
    System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string content = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Content as string;
    if (content != null)
        MessageBox.Show(content);
}
```

Comment: It's working now. I made one edit  - System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem instead ComboBoxItem Thanks

Comment: @Joozty You're welcome. (Usually you have a using `System.Windows.Controls;` and don't need the full qualified name of a class - therefore I didn't include it in my answer.) If my answer worked for you then you can also mark it as the accepted answer.